# Error: Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size

Tags: mysql, update, joomla-3.5

I have upgraded the joomla website to 3.5.1 and the module manager is showing error:

> Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size
>
> SQL=
>
> ```
> SELECT
>     a.id, a.title, a.note, a.position, a.module, a.language, a.checked_out,
>     a.checked_out_time, a.published as published, e.enabled as enabled, a.access,
>     a.ordering, a.publish_up, a.publish_down, l.title AS language_title,
>     l.image AS language_image, uc.name AS editor, ag.title AS access_level,
>     MIN(mm.menuid) AS pages, e.name AS name
> FROM `#__modules` AS a
> LEFT JOIN `#__languages` AS l ON l.lang_code = a.language
> LEFT JOIN #__users AS uc ON uc.id = a.checked_out
> LEFT JOIN #__viewlevels AS ag ON ag.id = a.access
> LEFT JOIN #__modules_menu AS mm ON mm.moduleid = a.id
> LEFT JOIN #__extensions AS e ON e.element = a.module
> WHERE (a.published IN (0, 1)) AND a.client_id = 0 AND e.client_id =0
> GROUP BY
>     a.id,
>     a.title,
>     a.note,
>     a.position,
>     a.module,
>     a.language,
>     a.checked_out,
>     a.checked_out_time,
>     a.published,
>     a.access,
>     a.ordering,
>     l.title,
>     l.image,
>     uc.name,
>     ag.title,
>     e.name,
>     l.lang_code,
>     uc.id,
>     ag.id,
>     mm.moduleid,
>     e.element,
>     a.publish_up,
>     a.publish_down,
>     e.enabled
> ```

And in the admin panel it shows `An error has occurred` message in every view.

I have tried these solution but no luck

1. Disabling system plugins
2. Increased `sort_buffer_size=512k`

Kindly, guide me through the solution.

Comment: Have you restarted the db server after changing the sort_buffer_size var?

Comment: @FFrewin Yes, I did and its showing me the changed size.

Comment: What happens if you try it with a higher value?

Comment: @FFrewin Do I need to increase it more? Like 1024 or 2048 or more higher?

Comment: This was raised as an issue at: https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/9432 - It looks like 512k should be sufficient for most websites.

Comment: @Joomler do you actually need to specify such a complex GROUP BY clause?  I've never seen a GROUP BY clause of that size and I seriously doubt it is necessary.  Lightening that clause would be my very first pursuit.